# Login issue - .bashrc permission denied?

Tags: linux, user-accounts, bashrc

I logged in as root user and create a new user and set the password.
But I am unable to switch to the newly created user.

What is the permission problem of .bashrc file with root user?

```
# adduser -m praveen
# passwd praveen
<password set>

# su praveen
bash: /home/monitor/praveen/.bashrc: Permission denied

# ls -al /home/monitor/praveen
-rw-r--r-- 1 praveen praveen  124 Jul 28 07:41 .bashrc
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`/home/monitor` was not in permission list of user praveen. Adding it fixed the problem.